# Azure Runbook still return error when using Get-PowerBIActivityEvent

Tags: powerbi, azure-powershell, azure-runbook, runbook, powerbi-api

I'm struggling to make my azure account automation runbook work.
Logging using `Login-PowerBIServiceAccount` is working correctly, but with these commands, `Get-PowerBIActivityEvent`, `Get-PowerBIWorkspace` I get the error:

```
Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.
```

I can't use `PowerShell -NoProfile` in a runbook and I can't downgrade `MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt` module. I did not have this issue in a previous version of the module. The actual version is 1.2.0.0.

Can you help me fix this?

Thank you,

Comment: I'm stuck with similar issue :) hoping for a response!

Comment: Have you find any alternative for this?